# A question about manifolds with boundaries.

Tags: manifolds

My topology textbook says the following:

> Let $S\subset \Bbb{R^2}$ be a closed disc. Then every point in $S$ is contained in a neighbourhood which is homeomorphic to that portion of a ball in $\Bbb{R^2}$ where $x_1,x_2\geq 0$.

I don't see how this is true for a point on the boundary of $S$. Any help would be great.

Comment: Who are $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$?

Comment: If they represent the coordinates then the key is in the phrase "that portion of the ball".

Answer (score 0):

Any point on the boundary will have a neighbourhood homeomorphic to a neighbourhood in $\mathbb{R}^2_+$; think of this pictorally - its neighbourhood will be a collection of interior points of the disk and a segment of the boundary of the disk. The same is true of a neighbourhood of $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ lying on its boundary.

Comment: Im not sure if the quality of this is good enough but it may help!! http://imgur.com/r9YNd5r